# Swift 4 - Convert string in double value with NSString

Tags: swift

I want to convert a `String` in a `NSString`, for obtaining a double value. But I have an error:

> Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads.

How can I fix this?

[image: NSString as! String]

Comment: The init for a String is `NSString(string:)` you need to have the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that.

Basically you can bridge cast `String` to `NSString`

```
let nsString = "12.34" as NSString
print(nsString.doubleValue)
```

rather than using an initializer (the error message says there is no appropriate initializer without a parameter label), but casting to `NSString` to get the `doubleValue` is the **wrong way in Swift**.

Get the `String`, use the `Double` initializer and unwrap the optionals safely

```
if let lat = array[indexPath.row]["lat"] as? String, 
   let latAsDouble = Double(lat) {
       // do something with latAsDouble
}
```

Comment: Thx vadian. I use your code for return a CLLocation and calculate the distance between two points in kilometers, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to use this syntax to convert

```
let myString = "556"
let myFloat = (myString as NSString).doubleValue
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 & 4**

**String to Double**

```
CartAmount = (response.object(forKey:"amount")as! NSString).doubleValue!
```

**Double to String**

```
let string = String(CartAmount)
```

Answer (score -1):

### swift 4 - String to Double || NSString to Double

**try this**

```
 let nsstring:NSString = "111.11"
        let str:String = "111.11"

        let tempString = (str as NSString).doubleValue
        print("String:-",tempString)

        let temp = nsstring.doubleValue
        print("NSString",temp)
```

### Output

```
String:- 111.11
NSString 111.11
```