# Fail to convert string to double Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder why following not work as I expected:

```
var amount: Double = 0.0
amount = dict["amount"] as? Double ?? 0.0
```

In log `dict["amount"]` is `Optional(5350.00)`, but `amount` is still 0. Am I using incorrect syntax?

Comment: show how you add the data to the dict..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ i did not, it's server response.

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47961682/5167909

Comment: if `dict["amount"]` logs `Optional(5350.0)` then it's definitely double. But... why does yours show 2 trailing zeroes as `Optional(5350.00)`?? Show us the code where you set/insert `dict["amount"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are getting value form dictionary using subscript then they return value either in

- `String?` (if you declared `let dict = [String: String]`)

or

- `Any?` (if you declared `let dict = [String: Any]` or `let dict = ["key1" : "value1", "key2" : 2.0]`)

So you need to fist convert it from any to string.

```
if let stringValue = dict["amount"] as? String {
  let dblValue = Double(stringValue) ?? 0.0
}
```

**EDIT:**

Explanation

[image]

See above image I have added 3 conditions. I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: @Mahedra GP i wonder why i cant try to cast Any? to Double before convert to string..

Comment: It depends what value you have store in...if you stored "35.01" and you try to convert it in Double then it will give you nil and if you stored `35.01` and you cat to `Double`

Comment: thank for your explanation, look like we could easily cast to double only in case that dict value is a double, not string like "35.0"

Answer (score 2):

Look like first I need to convert `Any`? to `String`?, then unwrap it to Double if I can.

I ended up with:

```
Double(dict["amount"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it will work with string and Double type value.

```
let doubleValue = Double(String(describing: dict["amount"] ?? "")) ?? 0
```

Comment: describing is not neccessary to use here.

Comment: yup, not neccessary here! but it will work with any type of value.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Casting from String to Double is wrong, do it sth like this-

```
var dict = ["amount": "3567"]
var amount: Double = 0.0
amount = Double(dict["amount"] ?? "0")!
print(amount)  // 3567.0
```

Comment: you better awoid force unwrap in such case.

Comment: In this case, i am using Nil-Coalescing Operator which makes sure an optional type Double always contains a value. So we can use force unwrap.

Comment: in dict["amount"] you can possible get something that is fail to convert to Double. You check only for data existance.

Answer (score -1):

Use this one:-
Make sure yourString contain digit. Anything will not be converted,

```
Double(yourString)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.